# IIS 7.5 Compression is not working when loading the page on a local computer

Tags: iis7, compression

If I try to access our website inside our servers using the remote desktop connection. YSlow and PageSpeed is reporting that our website are compressed. But If I try to access our website in my local computer, both the YSlow and PageSpeed reports that our site is not compressed.

I'm confused with it. I don't know anymore what configuration I needed to check to make sure compression is working.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a problem if there is a server in between which is decompressing the content, such as a load-balancer, CDN, or proxy.  If the content is sent encrypted on localhost, it will be sent encrypted to you unless there is a client in between which does not have the Accept-Encoding:gzip header in the request.

The best way to check for compression is to look at the response header in your browser.  The Content-Encoding header should say gzip or deflate.